# Linearization of a non-linear model

Tags: multivariable-calculus, laplace-transform, linear-approximation

Context:-Consider you are holding a plate of cookies in your hand at angle $x$ with force $k$(you may change this at your discretion.The plate puts a force $f$ on your hands. Some people take cookies out of the plate at random time thus decreasing $f$ and then accordingly you have to adjust $k$.The plate must be held at constant height(basically $x$ must remain constant).
Consider the function as follows
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=f(t)\sin(x(t))-k(t)x(t)...(1)$$
Linearize the given function  and rewrite it in terms of $\bar{x},\bar{f},\bar{k}$. Where bar denotes the difference between value at any given point of time and steady state value.
$$\text{At steady state there is no change in values of functions wrt time}$$.
$$\text{Attempt}$$
At steady state we have $0=f_s(t)\sin(x_s)-k_s(t)x_s(t)$.The general approach is to subtract this from (1) but
I can't make substantial process with this. My first thought was using Taylor series for the $\sin$ part but what's bugging me is the presence of $f(t)$ with it. I have come across spring-system models where we have 2nd order derivative but never across a function which has multiplication of both the dependent variables.
I couldn't even get a paper which relates to such kind of functions.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $x=0,x'=0$ is a steady state. There are not other steady states that can just be "read off". (Actually, there are probably not other steady states at all, unless $f$ and $k$ are a bit weird.) You can try to linearize the sine function to get dynamics near $(0,0)$. Depending on what $f$ and $k$ are, this may or may not be useful for studying the nonlinear problem. (It will be useful if for example $f-k < c$ for some $c<0$.)

Comment: @Ian I have added some context. Will this help to analyse my problem a bit further).F and k take into account the moment arm and the moment of inertia.

Comment: That doesn't help all that much, though it does suggest that $(0,0)$ is the steady state you're trying to examine.

Comment: Yeah I mean the problem is so weird that I dont even know how to describe this model in simple terms :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like section 5.3 in this [chapter](http://control.ucsd.edu/mauricio/courses/mae280a/chapter5.pdf) should help

I would go about it this way, first assign your state variables $x_i$

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = f(t)\sin(x(t))-k(t)x(t)$$

Let $$x_{1} = x(t)$$
$$x_{2} = \frac{dx}{dt}$$

Then just for the sake of convention,

$$u_{1} = f(t)$$

$$u_{2} = k(t)$$

Then substitute into our original equation

$$\dot x_{2} = u_{1}sin(x_{1}) - u_{2}x_{1}$$

$$\dot x_{1} = x_{2}$$

Now you can calculate the linearization matrices about the nominal point, the following is in traditional state space vector/matrix format.

$$ \dot x = f(x,u) $$

$ A = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $ evaluated at $x = \bar x, u = \bar u$

$ B = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} $ evaluated at $x = \bar x, u = \bar u$

Then the familiar state space equation appears:

$$ \dot{\bar{x}} = A \bar x + B \bar u $$

Comment: Thanks that solves the problem!